# MLB - process of signing guy off of streets

Tags: baseball, mlb

This is a theoretical question, but I am curious of the process. Let's say the owner of a major league ball club is driving around somewhere and sees a baseball game happening on the streets where a pitcher is throwing 250mph (yes I know not possible, but this is to exaggerate his skills). So obviously the owner is very intrigued and finds out the guy is just a regular guy who never played any organized baseball. Could that owner just sign him right there if he wanted to? Does he have to get drafted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some [rules about age and college attendance](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/draftday/faq.jsp), if the player is not in any of those groups, any team can sign him (or her) as an undrafted free agent. It actually [happens from time to time](http://m.mlb.com/news/article/11532374//). The examples I found are players who were in the drafts, but never got picked. In fact, this is a very common entrance method; as those rules above show, players from outside an "extended area" of the US do not enter the MLB draft, but can be signed directly.